# how do i change the layout of preferences screen in android

Tags: android-layout, android-preferences

i have a preferences screen , and i want to add a button, imageview etc all in a relative layout within the preferences screen.How do i do it?
The preferences screen has 3 checkboxpreferences.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to extend the Preference class, and use setWidgetLayoutResource on the constructor for your RelativeLayout. The widgetLayout is the area to the left of the title and summary. If you want to change the whole preference, you need to use setLayoutResource. In this case there are some restrictions:

> This layout should contain a ViewGroup
>   with ID widget_frame to be the parent
>   of the specific widget for this
>   Preference. It should similarly
>   contain title and summary.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setLayoutResource(int)